# Reading negative value from cells

Tags: excel, vba

The question is this .. When ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value is something like -1.3 my code fails ... What is causing this?

```
Function TestCell() As Integer
    Dim Boon As Integer
    Dim nextBoon As Integer
    Dim nextTwo As Integer
    Dim nextOne As Integer
    Dim nextThree As Integer

    Boon = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value
    nextBoon = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 6).Value
    nextTwo = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 7).Value
    nextOne = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 8).Value
    nextThree = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 9).Value
    If Boon <= 1.8 And Boon >= -1.8 Then
        If nextBoon <= 1000 And nextBoon >= -1000 Then
            If nextTwo <= 0.36 And nextTwo >= -0.36 Then
                If nextOne <= 0.13 And nextOne >= -0.13 Then
                    If nextThree <= 1.2 And nextThree >= -1.2 Then
                        TestCell = 1
                    Else
                        TestCell = 0
                    End If
                Else
                    TestCell = 0
                End If
            Else
                TestCell = 0
            End If
        Else
            TestCell = 0
        End If
    Else
       TestCell = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Cularis, I care less about upvoting... My only concern is on finding out why I was not getting what I expected. I am new to excel VBA .. Naturally, I shouldn't have asked such elementary question ...

Comment: Your question was only two lines of code.

Comment: @cularis He made a mistake in formatting. It is fixed now.

Comment: @TLP [This](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7191502/1) is an error in formatting?

Comment: @cularis There was code in there when I edited it. I do not know why that version is not in the revision history.

Comment: @user618677: what do you mean by `my code fails`. what happens? (or doesn't)

Comment: @user618677: run it step by step...you will see !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JMax said, use Double instead of Integer for Boon. I really wanted to give you 2 bits of advice since your code is 2x the length it could be:

First, don't use else statements. Just declare that the testcell is 0 and do your if-thens to see if you can change it to 1 or not.

Second, if you are only using a cell 2 times, there is no particular benefit to store it as a variable (on the flip-side you lose readability). Just use "cells(15, 5).value", etc. You shouldn't specify activesheet either - by default it uses the activesheet.

These 2 tips should help you out in the long run and it's good practice to follow.

**Update**:

Allow me to introduce a much faster, more effecient way to do this. You pass it in a 5 cell range. Doing it this way, you can just drag the formula all the way down your column and it'll work for every cell.

In your example, you'd call it by using:

> =TestCell(E14:I14)

```
Function TestCell(ByVal myRange As Range) As Long

Dim vArray As Variant
Dim result As Long
result = 0

vArray = myRange.Value

If vArray(1, 1) <= 1.8 And vArray(1, 1) >= -1.8 Then
    If vArray(1, 2) <= 1000 And vArray(1, 2) >= -1000 Then
        If vArray(1, 3) <= 0.36 And vArray(1, 3) >= -0.36 Then
            If vArray(1, 4) <= 0.13 And vArray(1, 4) >= -0.13 Then
                If vArray(1, 5) <= 1.2 And vArray(1, 5) >= -1.2 Then
                    result = 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

TestCell = result

End Function
```

**How it works**: The 5 cell range is converted to a variant array (which can hold Integers, strings, doubles, whatever). The checks are done using the varray since it's insanely fast, effecient, and you don't need to worry about data types (one of the major benifits is the ability to dump an entire range into a vArray as you see I do in my code). Since we set the result at 0, we don't need any else statements, you just do the if-thens to see if the value can be changed to 1 or not.

Using this method, the calculations can be done in microseconds, and the function updates itself everytime one of the 5 cells is changed, so you have real-time results.

Comment: I added some code to introduce what I feel is a very effecient and flexible way to do this. Hope you like it!

Comment: I have a lot to learn from you in my quest to get started with excel VBA. Do you offer free online course? :( Thanks so much, I owe you a lot.

Comment: Varray to me is array of arrays.. Then I am thinking that it should also work for E5:I7. Is that correct?

Comment: Varray is a single array of variant - meaning it can be an array of any type of data (string double long etc.). Varray is used since you can dump the 5 cell range into it in one move - an action not allowed with arrays of other. Your function compares values of 5 cells - you can't apply it on 15 cells without adding logic for the other 10. You can apply it to E5:I5, E6:I:6, etc.

Comment: This is it Variant .. I would expect the the elements of Varray to the accessed thus; Varray(i)

Comment: Check up on multi-dimensional arrays :)

Answer (score 3):

Your Boon is declared as an `Integer`>> http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/06bkb8w2(v=vs.80).aspx

So `Boon = ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value` will return `-1` if the `ActiveSheet.Cells(14, 5).Value` is `-1.3`

You need to use `Double` if you want it to work.

```
Function TestCell() As Integer
    Dim Boon As Double
```

Comment: Nice one JMax and congrats on 3000+!

Comment: @Issun: thanks :) but i'm sure you'll be there soon with your dictionaries vba answers